# React/Next.js code for a "back to top" button

Tags: react.js, next.js

Pretty new to React/Next.js. This is for a "back to top" button. Any thoughts on whether this can be improved? I haven't really got my head around when `useEffect` should be used, for example, but what I've written is running fine.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Chevron from '@/components/Icons/Chevron';

export default function BackToTop() {

  const scrollToTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    let scrollPosition = 0;

    const isScrollingDown = () => {      
      let scrollingDown = false;
      let newScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
      if (newScrollPosition > scrollPosition) {
        scrollingDown = true;
      }
      scrollPosition = newScrollPosition;
      return scrollingDown;
    };
    
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const scrollToTopButton = document.querySelector('[data-backToTopButton]');
      if (isScrollingDown() || window.pageYOffset == 0) {
        scrollToTopButton.classList.add('opacity-0', 'invisible');
        scrollToTopButton.classList.remove('opacity-100', 'visible');
      } else {
        scrollToTopButton.classList.remove('opacity-0', 'invisible');
        scrollToTopButton.classList.add('opacity-100', 'visible');
      }
    };
    
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

  });

  return (
    <div data-backToTopButton role="button" onClick={scrollToTop} aria-label="Back to top" title="Back to top" className="fixed bottom-4 right-2 z-10 bg-[#9147FF] text-white group w-[60px] h-[60px] rounded-full flex items-center justify-center shadow-back-to-top opacity-0 invisible">
      <Chevron width="30" height="20" extraClasses="transition-all duration-500 relative top-0 group-hover:-top-0.5 -mt-1" /> 
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: Title should explain what the code is doing, hope I understood it right.